# How can I check if the value of argv[i] is null and if it is true end the program

Tags: c

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){

    int toSleep;
    int produce; 
    int consume; 
    int i = 0;
    //get the values for sleep, produce, consume 
    toSleep = atoi(argv[1]);
    produce = atoi(argv[2]);
    consume = atoi(argv[3]);
    //check if the user input a vaild inpusts 

    //if(argc !=4){
   //printf("You are missing an input\n");
  //        exit(0);
  //}`enter code here`
    if(toSleep == '\0' ||  produce == '\0' || consume == '\0' ){
        printf("You are missing an input\n");
        exit(0);
    }else if (toSleep <=0 || produce<= 0 || consume <=0 ){
        printf("Please provide a vaild inputs \n");
        exit(0);
    }else {
    //continue to the program 
}
```

I am trying to make sure that the user will input exactly 3 inputs; if one is missing or null, I should print an error message and terminate the program. I always get this error when I tried to compile it

> ```
> ./a4  
>  makefile:5: recipe for target 'semaphore' failed make: ***
> [semaphore] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> ```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong here?

Comment: You commented out the `if` that uses `argc`, but that's about how you'd verify exact three arguments.  Is that error when you try to compile or when you try to run the program?

Comment: Note that if you pass `NULL` to `atoi()` then undefined behavior will occur. So it would be too late to check, also `'\0'` is just fancy notation for `0`, it's to indicate that you intend to compare with the *null* character in a string, but it would not mean that `atoi()`'s argument was `NULL`. What you want is so simple that I'm sincerly surprised that you asked, google that up.

Comment: I'm confused by the paragraph under the example.  What is 'semaphore'?  is that the name this program compiles to?  You might get more help if you include the makefile, the command-line you use to run it, and the output it produces (with good formatting)

Comment: I did the comment part and still give me the same error. Plus does it going to work if the user input less than or more than 3 items or not.

Comment: my make file is  a4: a4.c
 gcc -g -pthread -o a4 a4.c

semaphore:
 ./a4

Comment: @StephenNewell when I run it

Comment: You really should add a formatted version of the Makefile to the question.  If I'm guessing correctly at how to format that, `semaphore` is a  Makefile target with no pre-requisites, whose recipe just runs `a4`...with no arguments...so of course the program crashes...you're indexing past the bounds of argv.

Comment: Move the `if` before you access `argv`.  Of course it's going to crash if you're accessing out of bounds memory.

Answer (score 6):

Check the value of `argc`, it tells you how many arguments have been passed.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s sleep produce consume\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    toSleep = atoi(argv[1]);
    produce = atoi(argv[2]);
    consume = atoi(argv[3]);
    ....
}
```

Note that `argc` is the value of the number of arguments **plus** the filename
of the executed binary (more precisely how the binary was executed) and
`argv[0]` is always that string. So when `argc == 4`, 3 arguments have been
passed (`argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, `argv[3]`) and `argv[4] == NULL`. The `argv` list
is always `NULL` terminated.

If you wan to check if an individual `argv[i]` is `NULL`, then

```
if(argv[i] == NULL)
{
    // argv[i] is NULL
}
```

but you usually don't have to do these checks if you properly checked `argc`.
But sometimes it makes sense to check against `NULL`, for example when you have
variable number of arguments, when a program can take either 3 or 4 arguments,
then checking if `argv[3] == NULL` is also an option to see if the last optional
argument has been passed. But I prefer checking `argc` instead anyway.

Note also that `toSleep`, `produce` and `consume` are `int`, although the check

```
if(toSleep == '\0' ||  produce == '\0' || consume == '\0' )
```

is technically correct, I suggest you do

```
if(toSleep == 0 ||  produce == 0 || consume == 0 )
```

which shows your intentions more clearly.

Comment: Nice answer. It might be worth noting that the `argv[i] == NULL` checks are only safe for `i < argc`.  (well, I suppose <=)  just to drive the use of `argc` home.